# How to Configure Plugins while installing Vundle plugin for vim?

Tags: linux, vim, vundle

I'm trying to install Vundle plugin for vim and all I have done yet is : -

```
git clone http://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim.git ~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim
```

To proceed further i need to configure the plugin

on github i can see that
To Configure Plugins:

I need to Put some at the top of your .vimrc to use Vundle.

But i can't find any file .vimrc in my home directory.
So what i need to do? 
do i need to make a new directory with name .vimrc and if i do so then where i will put the code?
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to create that file yourself.

On unix-like systems:

```
$ cd
$ touch .vimrc
```

On Windows:

```
C:cd %userprofile%
C:vim _vimrc
```

Answer (score 1):

You are required to make a new `.vimrc` file not directory.

To make this file you can write :-

```
touch ~/.vimrc
```

This will be a hidden file where you will past those code and also you will need a `.vim` directory where your vundle plugin will get installed. And also in this `.vim` directory you may need to download few plugin to enhance your vim editor.